# var javascript to asp.net MVC model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

New to MVC, trying to pass a variable from Flash using FSCommand (works well with other functions) from one view to another.  The Javascript I am using:

```
function p1_DoFSCommand(command, args) {
            var p1Obj = InternetExplorer ? p1 : document.p1;
            if (command == "nameClip") {
                var  FlashName = [args];
            }
```

in the Homecontroller:

```
 public ActionResult Testing(string FlashName)
        {

            ViewData["Message"] = FlashName;

            return View();

        }
```

In the second view:

```
Html.Encode(ViewData["message"])
```

Would appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get the data to the Action method:

```
function p1_DoFSCommand(command, args) {
                var p1Obj = InternetExplorer ? p1 : document.p1;
                if (command == "nameClip") {
                    var  FlashName = [args];

                    // might have to replace '?' with '&'
                    var formData = "?FlashName=" + FlashName; 

                    $.post('/HomeController/Testing', formData, function(res)
                    {
                        // do stuff with response

                    }, "json");
    }
```

You'll also need to reference jQuery for this to work.

If you need to pass that value to another controller, simply change

```
$.post('/HomeController/Testing', formData, function(res)
```

to

```
$.post('/OtherController/Testing', formData, function(res)
```

**edit:**
I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but ViewData is a data construct that only has relevance in the Controller and when the View is being executed. By the time the JavaScript is running, it's in the context of a rendered page, so ViewData is meaningless. If, in your view you had

`<input id='MyMessage' type='hidden' value='<%=(string)ViewData['Message'] %>' />`,

you could then get the value you're looking for with

```
$('#MyMessage').val();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("MyMessage").value;
```

Comment: You can also use an object to build the parameters. `var formData = { FlashName: FlashName};`

Comment: Thank you for assistance, I am still getting null value for the var, do I need to change the HomeController! from 

            ViewData["Message"] = FlashName;

            return View();

        }

Comment: @hnabih, I've updated the answer in response to your question. Not sure if it's what you're asking though..

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will post it with the script as another question because commen only accept less words than I need

Comment: @hnabih, if you find that this is the correct answer it's good StackOverflow practice to accept it as such. Thanks